# wordpress to display vBulletin content

Tags: wordpress, optimization, vbulletin

I don't like the content display of vBulletin .. and I was thinking about using wordpress to do it 
How can I use wordpress to display the content of my already imple vBulletin forum ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use RSS feed ("yourforum.com/external.php") for a light integration. I do not know Wordpress but I'm pretty sure that you can find a "RSS feed reader" for it.
See [this](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/options_group_externaldata) and [that](http://www.vbulletin.com/docs/html/main/vboptions_group_external) links for documentation.

Or, if you want a real integration you can use a bridge, see theses links : for [vB4](http://wp-vb-bridge.obscurecloud.com/) ([lite version @vb.org](http://www.vbulletin.org/forum/showthread.php?t=296819))  ,for [vB3](http://www.lampwrights.com/showthread.php?t=41)

Many people are using vB with Wordpress, you will find more help on www.vbulletin.org.